# Python AttributeError: partially initialized module

Tags: python, time

I'm making a script that runs the script every 10 seconds (for example)

But i get this:

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'schedule' has no attribute 'every' (most likely due to a circular import)

My code:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(3).seconds.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: What's the name of your file? If it's `schedule.py` change it to something else, you just end up importing itself.

Comment: check your local modules names, probably one of them is called `schedule.py`

Comment: Your code is working on my end. Did you install the `schedule` package?

Comment: What's your file name? Or do you have any other file in the folder your file is in with a name like `schedule` or `time`?

Comment: Hello! thanks for responding, i called my file schedule.py!
I now renamed it. 
    schedule.run.pending()
AttributeError: module 'schedule' has no attribute 'run'

Comment: @JohnJain `schedule.run_pending()` was correct ignore below answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Azat Ibrakov & Abdul Aziz Barkat for saying that i need to rename my python script.

Thanks to joao for saying that its "run_pending" and not "run.pending".

Working code:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(3).seconds.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(3).seconds.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run.pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either?

```
    import schedule import time
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Uh could you explain this?

Comment: It's not working. `schedule` has no attribute `run`

Comment: It's run_pending (underscore), not run.pending (dot).