# Why am I very-occasionally getting an ImportError using django-constance?

Tags: python, django

Once every few hundred thousand requests I see one of these:

```
ImportError at /
cannot import name 'Config' from partially initialized module 'constance.base' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/constance/base.py)
```

I cannot identify any rhyme or reason. It doesn't correspond with accessing `constance` admin, just randomly occurs. My best guess is it's something to do with the `LazyObject` in [`constance's __init__.py`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance/blob/master/constance/__init__.py), and maybe random race-conditions in restarting expired `gunicorn` workers or something?!

I'm using:

- Python 3.9.2
- Django 3.2
- `django-constance = {extras = ["database"],version = "==2.8.*"}`
- `"constance"` and `"constance.backends.database"` in `INSTALLED_APPS` (at top)
- `CONSTANCE_BACKEND = "constance.backends.database.DatabaseBackend"`
- `"constance.context_processors.config"` in `TEMPLATES[0]["OPTIONS"]["context_processors"]`

All my code does is `from constance import config` and access `config` attributes in the standard way in python code and Django templates.

For what it's worth, we've been using `django-constance` on this site for years, but never saw this error until we upgraded to `2.8.0` (from `2.6.0`). We were using Django 3.1 when it first appeared, but has also occurred since upgrading to 3.2.

I cannot find any similar error reports on https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance/

Any ideas what could be causing this and how to resolve it?

Comment: Errors like this can be caused by module naming conflicts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66276332/python-attributeerror-partially-initialized-module), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59762996/how-to-fix-attributeerror-partially-initialized-module) to name just a few examples). Have you looked into that?

Comment: Yes, I've searched for that possibility but don't think it is the case. Also because it is reporting `constance.base` and I definitely don't have any files named that.

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug in constance that has been solved in [this](https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance/pull/446) pull request.

The root of the problem is that prior to this pull request constance testsuite  didn't run tests on Django 3.2, which is been fixed and the changes that caused your error are also outed and fixed.

That means in  [`constance's __init__.py`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance/blob/master/constance/__init__.py), now there is an if clause separating current handling of importation in Django 3.2 from the older Django versions.

Comment: Hmm, I had already seen that as-yet-unreleased commit, but I don't see how it could fix the issue. Surely it just addresses [the deprecation of the variable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/3.2/#automatic-appconfig-discovery) but wouldn't actually affect import mechanisms as Django will still use `constance.apps.ConstanceConfig` automatically, it just doesn't need to be told explicitly to do so after Django 3.2.

Comment: @DrMeers An `import django` was added to top and there was an explicitly check for django to be lower than 3.2, It isn't far fetched to assume there was a bug with the new `AppConfig` system that required django import and not defining the variable since it is very prone to circular imports.

Comment: I am the author of that PR and I can say for sure that it did not fix any bug. All I did was run tests over django 3.2 and add a django version check to avoid warnings. `RemovedInDjango41Warning: 'constance' defines default_app_config = 'constance.apps.ConstanceConfig'. Django now detects this configuration automatically. You can remove default_app_config.`

Comment: I've managed to somewhat diagnose the issue today -- see my answer below, and reported GitHub issue

Answer (score 2):

OK, I've managed to reproduce the issue and track down the likely cause.

I managed to trigger it once using Django's `runserver`, on the first request handled, but in hundreds of subsequent restarts/attempts I couldn't make it recur.

I then instead ran a couple of local `gunicorn` worker threads with a low requests-per-worker threshold, and spammed the local port with rapid-fire requests, and sure enough the `ImportError` occurs every now and then.

The issue seems to be this:

- `constance.__init__` uses a `django.utils.functional.LazyObject` which, once lazily evaluated, imports `constance.base` and instantiates a `Config` from that module.
- `constance.base.Config.__init__` uses `constance.utils.import_module_attr` to import the backend specified in the project settings, which in turn uses `importlib.import_module` to import, in my case, `constance.backends.database.DatabaseBackend`.
- `constance.backends.database.__init__` also imports `config` from `...` (`constance`), thus potentially creating an import loop.

It seems there is a rare race condition in which `LazyConfig._setup` tries to import `constance.base.Config` while `constance.base` hasn't be fully initialised. I injected some debugging statements to demonstrate, and the buggy sequence looks like this:

```
[2021-09-15 09:35:10 +1000] [13504] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13504
BEGIN constance.__init__.LazyConfig._setup() vars(self): {'_wrapped': <object object at 0x108da8340>}
BEGIN constance.__init__.LazyConfig._setup() vars(self): {'_wrapped': <object object at 0x108da8340>}
constance.base imported
constance.base.Config.__init__: importing constance.backends.database.DatabaseBackend
ImportError at /
cannot import name 'Config' from partially initialized module 'constance.base' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/constance/base.py) 
EXIT constance.__init__.LazyConfig._setup() vars(self): {'_wrapped': <constance.base.Config object at 0x10fa7ea30>}
```

It seems to only happen when `_setup` is called twice in a row like that, before `constance.base` is imported, then the two threads seem to race from that point.

I guess I'll open a GitHub issue on the `django-constance` repository to resolve the issue.

Comment: Reported here: https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance/issues/452

Comment: Nice, was gunicorn using gthread workers or sync ones?

Comment: gthread workers

Comment: Oh, I see, there are stuff that doesn't work right out of the box with gthreads, and it doesn't give a real advantage except concurrent handling more idle things(which is big, but not enough to pay for a thread-safe code). Most solutions I saw either use sync, or gevent/eventlet, since in between there is little.

Comment: Well it did also occur using Django's runserver, so I'm not convinced it's gthread-specific.